# Adding 1 hour to java.util.Calendar object(31-DEC-2015 23:00:00) gives 01-JAN-2015 00:00:00 2015

Tags: java, datetime

This is my Java code

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

c.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11);
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 31);
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 22);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println("date  is : "+sdf.format(c.getTime()));

c.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);

System.out.println("date2  is : "+sdf.format(c.getTime()));
```

and here is the output

```
date  is : 31-Dec-2015 23:00:00
date2  is : 01-Jan-2015 00:00:00
```

Why is the year not changing to 2016 in the 2nd print statement?

Comment: Your code doesn't fit the output. It returns "date is : 31-Dec-2015 22:00:00" and "date2 is : 31-Dec-2015 23:00:00"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and it is working as you need, but you should change the format to

```
dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! that helps